# Cern ROOT XCode IDE does not compile

Tags: xcode, ide, root-framework

I followed the [Setup Guide of another Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964395/setting-up-root-from-cern-in-xcode-linking-the-librariers-correctly) and got a working example using XCode as ROOT IDE. Now I tried to include the Minuit2 [example code](https://root.cern.ch/numerical-minimization) within the same project:

```
#include "Minuit2/Minuit2Minimizer.h"
#include "Math/Functor.h"

double RosenBrock(const double *xx )
{
    const double_t x = xx[0];
    const double_t y = xx[1];
    const double_t tmp1 = y-x*x;
    const double_t tmp2 = 1-x;
    return 100*tmp1*tmp1+tmp2*tmp2;
}

int main()
{
    // Choose method upon creation between:
    // kMigrad, kSimplex, kCombined,
    // kScan, kFumili

    ROOT::Minuit2::Minuit2Minimizer min ( ROOT::Minuit2::kMigrad );

    min.SetMaxFunctionCalls(1000000);
    min.SetMaxIterations(100000);
    min.SetTolerance(0.001);

    ROOT::Math::Functor f(&RosenBrock,2);
    double step[2] = {0.01,0.01};
    double variable[2] = { -1.,1.2};

    min.SetFunction(f);

    // Set the free variables to be minimized!
    min.SetVariable(0,"x",variable[0], step[0]);
    min.SetVariable(1,"y",variable[1], step[1]);

    min.Minimize();

    const double *xs = min.X();
    std::cout << "Minimum: f(" << xs[0] << "," << xs[1] << "): "
    << RosenBrock(xs) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I tested the code as a root macro and it worked fine, but trying to compile it within XCode yields the following errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>       defined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>         "ROOT::Minuit2::Minuit2Minimizer::SetFunction(ROOT::Math::IBaseFunctionMultiDim const&)", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o

and serveral more undefined symbols.

**What did I do wrong?**

---

I installed ROOT with Macports via

```
sudo port install root6
```

and made sure that the variant +minuit2 is installed. Then I added the **Search Paths** and **Linking**:

```
Targets > Build Settings > User Header Search Paths > Debug > /opt/local/libexec/root6/include/root
Targets > Build Settings > Other Linker Flags > Debug > -L/opt/local/libexec/root6/lib/root -lCore -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -lMultiProc -lpthread -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/libexec/root6/lib/root -stdlib=libc++ -lm -ldl
```

which I got from

```
root/bin/root-config --libs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this Question myself:
You have to add

```
-lMinuit2
```

to the other Flags in your Build settings. 
Somehow

```
root-config --libs
```

does not automatically add the minuit2 linker.

Comment: `root-config --libs` does not add all root libraries. it is only a minimal set of core libraries. Usually when you get linker errors you can check the `*.rootmap` files in `root-config --libdir` which library contains the classes you're missing.